# Search across a row for a series of values in r

Tags: r

It's a complicated task to explain, but I am trying to look across several columns, row by row, to search for a pattern of 3 or more consecutive occurrences of `FALSE`, but only if this has been preceded by at least one instance of `TRUE`.

Where this pattern is found, I would like to add a new column `date_lost`, showing the date at which this occurred (dates are taken from the column headings - I know this isn't the best way to name columns, but this is how the dataframe was set up)

A simple dataframe might be as shown below:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~`01/01/18`, ~`02/01/18`, ~`03/01/18`, ~`04/01/18`, ~`05/01/18`,
    1,        NA,        NA,      TRUE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    2,      TRUE,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,
    3,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,
    4,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    5,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,      TRUE,
    6,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  )

> df
# A tibble: 7 x 6
     id `01/01/18` `02/01/18` `03/01/18` `04/01/18` `05/01/18`
  <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>     
1     1 NA         NA         TRUE       TRUE       FALSE     
2     2 TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
3     3 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE      
4     4 FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE       FALSE     
5     5 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       TRUE      
6     6 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       FALSE     
7     7 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

The function would identify that this pattern is found in rows 2 and 3 and, in the new column `date_lost`, add the dates (`05/01/18` for row 2, and `04/01/18` for row 3). The other rows could have `NA` if this pattern is not found, as below:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
     id `01/01/18` `02/01/18` `03/01/18` `04/01/18` `05/01/18` date_lost
  <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <chr>    
1     1 NA         NA         TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      NA       
2     2 TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      05/01/18 
3     3 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       04/01/18 
4     4 FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      NA       
5     5 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       TRUE       NA       
6     6 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      NA       
7     7 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

I'm sure this can be done in an elegant way in `r`, but I just haven't been able to find such a way. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses some reshaping (work with columns and not with rows) and some grouping in order to spot *(3+)* consecutive FALSE cases with *(1+)* TRUE before them.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~`01/01/18`, ~`02/01/18`, ~`03/01/18`, ~`04/01/18`, ~`05/01/18`,
    1,        NA,        NA,      TRUE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    2,      TRUE,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,
    3,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,
    4,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    5,      TRUE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,      TRUE,
    6,     FALSE,     FALSE,     FALSE,      TRUE,     FALSE,
    7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
  )


df %>%
  gather(date, value, -id) %>%                      # reshape data
  arrange(id) %>%                                   # arrange data by id
  group_by(id2 = rleid(id, value)) %>%              # create a new grouping (to spot consequtive FALSE cases)
  mutate(value = ifelse(is.na(as.character(value)), 
                        ".", 
                        as.character(value)),       # update value variable (NAs will break the grouping, so we replace them with ".")
         false_in_row = sum(value == "FALSE")) %>%  # count how many FALSE in a row
  group_by(id) %>%                                  # group by id column
  mutate(flag = cumsum(value == "TRUE")) %>%        # create a flag to spot if you had TRUE before FALSE cases
  filter(flag >= 1 & false_in_row >= 3) %>%         # keep only conditions you specified
  summarise(date_lost = nth(date, 3)) %>%             # get date the matches your conditions
  right_join(df, by="id")                           # join original dataset

# # A tibble: 7 x 7
#      id date_lost `01/01/18` `02/01/18` `03/01/18` `04/01/18` `05/01/18`
#   <dbl> <chr>     <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>     
# 1     1 NA        NA         NA         TRUE       TRUE       FALSE     
# 2     2 05/01/18  TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE     
# 3     3 04/01/18  TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE      
# 4     4 NA        FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE       FALSE     
# 5     5 NA        TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       TRUE      
# 6     6 NA        FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       FALSE     
# 7     7 NA        NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Thanks - amazing work. I have edited the `summarise(date_lost = last(date))` command to now read `summarise(date_lost = nth(date, 3))`, which is the actual answer I needed (date at which the 3rd `FALSE` appeared). Thanks again!

Comment: It's not obvious from the example you posted, as you don't have any example of 4 or more FALSE cases in a row. I've accepted the edit assuming that you know what you're talking about :D

Comment: Yeah, that was a slight failing in the dummy dataset I provided. Anyway, this now works as intended

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using `tidyverse`, `data.table` and `zoo`:

```
df %>%
  gather(var, val, -c(1)) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  group_by(temp1 = rleid(val)) %>%
  mutate(temp2 = seq_along(temp1)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(date_lost = ifelse(lag(val, 3) == TRUE & val == FALSE & temp2 == 3, var, NA)) %>%
  summarise(date_lost = ifelse(all(is.na(date_lost)) == TRUE, NA_character_, na.locf(date_lost))) %>%
  right_join(df, by = "id")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution using `rle` :

```
rle_mat <- t(apply(df[-1],1,function(x) sequence(rle(x)$length))) *!df[-1]
df$date_lost <- apply(rle_mat,1,function(x) {
  which_3 <-which(x==3)[1]
  cond    <- which_3 > which(x==0)[1]
  if(isTRUE(cond[[1]])) names(x)[which_3] else NA
})
df
# # A tibble: 7 x 7
#      id `01/01/18` `02/01/18` `03/01/18` `04/01/18` `05/01/18` date_lost
#   <dbl> <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <lgl>      <chr>    
# 1     1 NA         NA         TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      <NA>     
# 2     2 TRUE       TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      05/01/18 
# 3     3 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       04/01/18 
# 4     4 FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      <NA>     
# 5     5 TRUE       FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       TRUE       <NA>     
# 6     6 FALSE      FALSE      FALSE      TRUE       FALSE      <NA>     
# 7     7 NA         NA         NA         NA         NA         <NA>
```

`x` reaches 3 when `FALSE` appears for the 1st time, it had to be `TRUE` first though, and `TRUE` values are 0 in `rle_mat`, hence the inequality in te 2nd call.

Comment: I can see the output works for you but for some reason I can't get it to work for me. I just get a column with `NA`s

Comment: I believe it was due to a breaking change in `isTRUE`'s definition between versions. I updated my answer and made it more readable

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html in *"CHANGES IN R 3.5.0"* :  *"isTRUE() is more tolerant and now true in : `x <- rlnorm(99); isTRUE(median(x) == quantile(x)["50%"])`"* , I assume with your R version it'd be `FALSE`.